# Slot / Signal in QML with an another page than main.qml

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm making an programm where I need the user to fill up some info. I have my main.qml with the menu,  and my page SubPage.qml where the user can access the form to fill it up.

Now the form is fill up, I would like to send the info to the main.cpp to treat it. 
All my attempts were unsuccessful ...

here my main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlComponent>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QtQml>
#include <QDebug>
#include "generalsettings.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine2;

    GeneralSettings generalSettings1;
    QQmlComponent component(&engine2, QUrl((QStringLiteral("qrc:/SubPage.qml"))));

    QObject *element = engine.rootObjects().value(0);
    //QQuickWindow *window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow *>(element);

    QObject::connect(component, SIGNAL(saveGeneralSettings(QString)),
                       &generalSettings1, SLOT(registerGeneralSettings(QString)));

    return app.exec();
}
```

My SubPage.qml
I only put the button with the signal

```
 Button{
     id:buttonRight
     text:"Right"
     anchors.margins: 10
     x:visualConditionsContainer.x + maxCardWidth/2 - buttonRight.width + visualConditionsContainer.width/2
     y:maxCardHeight +visualConditionsContainer.y +40
     onClicked:{
        if(datePickerContainer.x != pageGeneralSettings.width){
            selectedCard = datePickerContainer
            if(currentTimeDate.checked){
                timePickerContainer.x = pageGeneralSettings.width
            }
            animateGoRight.start()
        }else if(timePickerContainer.x != pageGeneralSettings.width){
            selectedCard = timePickerContainer
            animateGoRight.start()
        }else if(globalConfigContainer.x != pageGeneralSettings.width){
            selectedCard = globalConfigContainer
            animateGoRight.start()
        }else if(visualConditionsContainer.x != pageGeneralSettings.width){
            pageStack.push(Qt.resolvedUrl("PageModifications.qml"))
            DataManager.registerGeneralSettings(currentTimeDate.checked,Qt.formatDate(datePicker.selectedDate, "d MMMM yyyy"),Qt.formatTime(timePicker.getCurrentTime(), "hh:mm:ss"), dayDurationTextField.text,isFarCulling.checked, isEnableLensFlare.checked,radioButton(rateReflection.current.text), sliderVisibility.value, sliderLight.value, sliderTurbidity.value )
            pageGeneralSettings.saveGeneralSettings("coucou c'est QML")
        }

     }
     backgroundColor: Theme.accentColor
 }
```

thank you for your help

Comment: what is the meaning of several `QQmlApplicationEngine` instances? If you want to connect 2 qml files why you need to do that through C++ and not directly?

Comment: My application need at the end to produce an XML file with all the data wrote by the user. This XML file will be generate with c++. I used 2 QQmlApplicationEngine because throught tutorials and doc, I saw it was the only way to transfert data from and to c++. I need to load the main.qml to let the user choose what menu he wants to select but I also need the SubPage.qml to send back the info collected. Is it clearer ?

Comment: Accessing C++ part from QML and vice versa is very very simple and doesn't require creating of 2 engines. Look at [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-topic.html) page to have some idea. I guess you will get right answer after posting some [mvse](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code

Comment: Yes, but in all this examples, there is always one page QML which interact with the c++, is it possible to have 2 QML pages which interact with the c++ ?

Comment: Sure, you can have as many pages as you want, connected to single engine and all of them can interact with C++ with no problem.

Comment: But it is IN the engine that I put my qml page address, so how  can I connect severals qml page with only one engine ?